# find out in which organizational unit are a given computer list in my domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou

I have a list of hundreds od computers selected from my domain. I would like to make a report that shows up in which `OU` are all of them. I found out that this cmdlet can perform the task I need:

```
PS C:\Users\digiacomo.a-rti> Get-ADComputer "FIDS156041" -Properties DistinguishedName
```

but instead of a single computer `FIDS156041`, I want to pass to it as a parameter, a (txt or csv) file containing my list of computers, and if possible, output the result in another file that contains two columns: computer names and their `OU`. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
#load a list of computers
$computerList = Get-Content "computerList.txt"

#results array
$results = @()

#for each computer
foreach($computerName in $computerList) {
    #add result of command to results array
    $results += Get-ADComputer $computerName -Properties Name, DistinguishedName | Select Name, DistinguishedName
}

#send results to CSV file
$results | Export-Csv "computerOUs.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you sodawillow for your answer. I will get back to work on Sunday and will check if it works. Thanks once again for the time being.